# Hitting a word then highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried in hours to make this work.

I need to have a function which highlights the char if it's correct.

Ex, word is "halluluja" and i have a input field.

When user hitting "h" it has to make "h" red in "halleluja", if user hit "ha" after, it has to highlight the a. and so on.

I have tried something with substr, without any luck.

```
'typing':function(e){
         var c = w.length; //The word length, ex. halleluja
         for ( i=0;i<e.length;i++){ //foreach each
            var o = e.substr(0, e.length); var l = w.substr(i,i+1); //my typing substr, and the char substr
            if ( o.toLowerCase() == l.toLowerCase()){ //correct
                //highlight the letter.
            }
         }
      },
```

The word container is here which outputs the word in that container.

```
    document.getElementById('wordContainer').innerHTML = w;
```

Comment: Make a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: When the user hits `a` do you want only a to be highlighted or both h and a to be red?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tqHRA/

html:

```
<div id="preview">hello world</div>

<input type='text' id='txt' />​
```

JavaScript:

```
var source = 'hello world';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt').keyup(function(){
         var text = $(this).val();
         var replaced = source.replace(text, '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>');
         $('#preview').html(replaced);
    });
});​
```

Comment: And here is the fork http://jsfiddle.net/tqHRA/1/ that is case-insensitive and highlights only the begining.